# Reproduce Authlogic Hash in PHP function

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, authlogic

Given that I know the hashed password, salt & original password generated with Authlogic (ruby on rails gem).

Is it possible in PHP devise a function to check if a users password matches the users Ruby Authlogic hashed_pw in the DB? I need to integrate an existing PHP app with the ruby app without resetting all the Ruby users passwords.

I tried something like below but it didn't seem to work

```
function passwordhash($password, $salt)
{
 return hash('sha512', "{$password}:{$salt}");
}
echo passwordhash("orange","NsxUt51YVzK4dFeVJOj");
output: 7b4a69291354dc3591e490f47f29d5a4a4b6d7faa23d01a1ee595b917526b65e2dda48e978c46b81dde0269adc3f853a36c075d236eb89c8f6b21811fe3da1bb
```

The DB info is

```
crypted_password 
f777c545bf9844faaa5f3b129e77e4199539793d907e397ddc97d1bb747a30d402201bd11ed9ca0eaecbf3b9652b314aa919d65904c64d4169ce0e1ac1c526a4

password_salt
NsxUt51YVzK4dFeVJOj

real password
orange
```

It seems like this should be possible what am I missing?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: I am trying to do the same in java, did it work for you in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My perusal of the authlogic code suggests 2 things:

- It doesn't use : to separate the password from the salt (i.e. the first string to be digested is `orangeNsxUt51YVzK4dFeVJOj`
- It does a sha512 digest on the output of the first process and repeats this process 20 times

The other thing is that authlogic supports a large number of hashing strategies - make sure that you're trying to reimplement the correct one! It certainly looks like the 20 fold sha512 is the right one though.

Link:  https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/crypto_providers/sha512.rb

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce the ruby gem authlogic sha512 implementation like this:

```
  /**
   * implements ruby gem authlogic sha512 encryption
   * @param $password
   * @param $salt
   * @return string
   */
  private function sha512hash($password, $salt) {
    $strechtes = 20;
    $digest = $password . $salt;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $strechtes; $i++) {
      $digest = hash('sha512', $digest);
    }
    return $digest;
  }
```